# Send push from Cloud code to channels

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

To send push from Parse cloud code I have code like this:

```
var channelList = ["IssuesAnswers"];

if (isNotificationNeed) {
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo('user_email', owner.get("username"));

    Parse.Push.send({
        channels: channelList,
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
            action: "com.mycompany.myapp.NEW_MESSAGE",
            issue_id: issue.id, 
            issue_title_preset: issue.get("title"),
            message_id: request.object.id,
        }
    },
    {
        success: function () {
            console.log("Notification sent!");
            // Push was successful
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
}
```

It doesn't work. No errors in log of console and no log in "Push" section. 
But if I comment line:

```
//channels: channelList,
```

It works. But my aim to send push to single installation IF user subscribed to chanel. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use **both** *channels* and *where* in your Push.send body.

You should write something like this :

```
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo('user_email', owner.get("username"));
pushQuery.containedIn('channels', channelList);
```

and remove *channels* from the Push.send body.